# Stop jQuery addClass() from animating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, addclass

How do I prevent jQuery's `.addClass()` from animating the resulting change? Even a duration of `0` has no effect:

```
$('#go_button').addClass('big_button',0);
```

In this example, once the page loads, the `#go_button` object animates the changes inherited from the `.big_button` class. I just want the changes brought on by the new class to be instantaneous.

Comment: `addClass` is instantaneous, unless there are some kind of `transition` defined within the CSS styles for that class, in which case you would need to remove those, or separate them to another class.

Comment: agree with @RoryMcCrossan - `addClass` doesn't animate unless it has been told to with CSS transitions

Comment: Yeah... that's what I thought, @RoryMcCrossan. There's a `:hover` transition on the object, could that be affecting things?

Comment: Possibly. If you could edit your question include the CSS I can give you a more definite answer.